# Build two different Docker-Compose instances from git directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on a Project where I create a WebApp that is hackable (via XSS, SQL-Injections etc.) for demonstration purposes. I also have a version of the App that is "secure". They are both existing in the same GIT repository, but on different branches. To be able to run both Apps at the same time, I wanted to start them in separate, disjoint docker-compose instances (consisting of a Frontend, Backend and Database). But since they are in the same directory on my PC and I just change the contents with git, it overrides the instance I created first with the newer one. My guess is that docker tags the docker-compose instances by naming them after the directory where the docker-compose.yml is to be found.

Here I have a picture to illustrate what I mean by "Docker-Compose instance". This is getting overridden every time I do a `docker-compose build` followed by a `docker-compose up`. I want to be able to have two disjoint instances of it. One being "SecureForum" and one being "HackableForum".
[image: Docker-Compose Instance]

How can I use a command like `docker-compose build` in a way that results in two different instances, even though I'm doing it in the same repository. Is there maybe a way to tag the different docker-compose instances, so they don't override each other?

I want to avoid to create a copy of the whole repository in order to run the `docker-compose build` command from different directories so they would not override eachother.

Docker-Compose verison: 3.8

I hope it was understandable what my problem is, and what I am trying to achieve. I am new to Stackoverflow so any help with being more precise with my question is apreciated :)

Comment: Use `git worktree` to check out both branches in two different directories. That should solve your problem.

Comment: You can use the `-p` switch to give each version a unique name. Like `docker-compose -p hackableforum up`. Then they won't override each other. You might run into host port conflicts though.

Comment: The "...naming after directory..." supposition is exactly correct, and the `docker-compose -p` option @HansKilian suggests overrides that.  The linked question describes basically this exact case.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be suboptimal usage of git branches, so I would merge them, have differently named files (code, Dockerfiles, etc...) for the secure and insecure versions of your app and then roll it all into one big docker-compose file that uses two separate networks (one for the secure apps, the other for the insecure).

However, if you want to stay with your current setup simply create a new folder (with another name than your current folder), clone the same repository, switch to the insecrure branch and start docker-compose in the new folder.
Now switch back to the original folder, switch to the secure branch and start docker-compose there.